# Writing an implementation of deque class

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, deque

I am currently in the midst of defining my own class of Deque called `myDeque` using ListNodes. A problem I am facing concerns the `remove()` method. How do you modify the Deque to point to the node behind back and delete what used to be "back"? Thank you

```
private ListNode<E> front;  // Reference to first ListNode in the Deque
private ListNode<E> back;   // Reference to last ListNode in the Deque
private int numElems;       // Current number of ListNodes in the Deque

public MyDeque() {
    front = null;
    back = null;
    numElems = 0;
}

public void addLast(E e) {
 if (numElems == 0){
front = new ListNode<E>(e,null);
back = front;
} else {
back.next = new ListNode<E>(e,null);      
back = back.next;
}
numElems += 1;
}

public boolean add(E e) {
if (numElems == 0){
front = new ListNode<E>(e,null);
back = front;
} else {
ListNode<E> prevData = back;
back.next = new ListNode<E>(e,null);     
back = back.next;
}
numElems += 1;
return true;
}

public boolean remove(Object o) {
  if (numElems == 0){
  throw new NoSuchElementException();
  }
    return false;
}

 public E removeLast() {
if (numElems == 0){
throw new NoSuchElementException();
}
else{
numElems = numElems - 1;  
}
return null;
}
```

Comment: Java already has a [`Deque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (and a few implementations, like [`ArrayDeque`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html)). Why can't you use one of those?

Comment: This is for a project and the code we use must be implemented ourselves to better understand the listnode data structure

Answer (score 0):

```
back = back.back; //modify the Deque to point to the node behind back 
back.next = null; //and delete what used to be "back"
```

Comment: When I try and add those statements into my method, it throws me "cannot find symbol" error

Comment: While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how and why this code is different from the code in the question, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.